# removing div from paragraph using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following problem:

I have :

```
<p class="site_text"><div>Some text</div></p>
```

I am trying to remove the div tag and to leave the text intact, and i have the following code

```
$('p.site_text').remove('<div>');
$('p.site_text').remove('</div>');
```

which does not remove the div from the paragraph. Anyone can help?

Regards, Zoran

Comment: `div` inside `p` is not valid any way. Did you think on fixing the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a `div` inside a `p` tag, it both violates html rules and doesn't work in Chrome. If you replace the `p` with a `div`, you can use the following code:
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aX3Hp/1/
JS:

```
$('div.site_text div').wrapInner('<span/>').children().unwrap();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="site_text"><div>Some text</div></div>
```

Comment: You can just unwrap the contents `$('.site_text div').contents().unwrap();`

Comment: Well this is how the WYSIWYG editor do it. So, i have to find a way to remove that div tag.

Comment: Musa, i just test your solution and it doestn't work. <div> tag is still there.

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery replaceWith()

```
<p class="site_text">
    <!-- add some inline styles so we can see when div is removed -->
    <div style='color:red'>Some text</div>
    <div style='color:blue'>Another div</div>
</p>

$("div").each(function(){
   var obj = $(this);
   obj.replaceWith(obj.html());
});
```

- Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s5CUF/2/ (IE10, FF 20, Chrome 26)
- See: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

### Validity

However, as kpsuperplane points out, the starting HTML is invalid. It will be valid after running this script, **but** hierarchical jQuery selectors will not work as expected (try it), because the browser tries to correct the markup.

The browser interprets your structure more like:

```
<p class="site_text"></p>
<div style='color:red'>Some text</div>
<div style='color:blue'>Another div</div>
<p></p>
```

As long as you mindful of the selector ramifications of the invalid structure, `replaceWith()` appears to work correctly even with invalid markup.

### Using a More Restrictive Selector

Chances are, you don't want to remove all `divs` on your site, but you can't use the `p` to qualify the selector because the browser doesn't think the `div` is inside the `p`.

However, you could use the `p`'s parent to qualify the selector.

```
<!-- actual -->
<div id="searchresults">
    <p class="site_text">
        <div>Some text</div>
        <div>Another div</div>
    </p>
</div>

<!-- how the browser interprets -->
<div id="searchresults">
    <p class="site_text"></p>
    <div>Some text</div>
    <div>Another div</div>
    <p></p>
</div>

// a more restrictive selector
var divs = $("#searchresults > div");
```

- [Example using an outer wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/s5CUF/4/)

Comment: Tim the code break the html totally. I tried with $("p.site_text div").each(function(){ but the div is still there.

Comment: That's because of the invalid structure. As far as the browser is concerned, the `div` is not inside the `p`. Instead, it's probably inside the `p`'s parent; can you use the parent to qualify the selector?

Comment: Added some more detail as to how you might better qualify the selector.

Comment: Tim, i get lost here...my outer div is named searchresults. so i am trying to use this:  var div = $("#outer > searchresults");
 
 $("div").each(function(){
   var obj = $(this);
   obj.replaceWith(obj.html());
});
 
}); but the layout get broken 100%

Comment: Doesn't work again. Will try this again tomorow, here is 04:30 AM, have to get some sleep.Thanks for the help anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Though your html is not valid, still you can do it in similar valid scenario by using:

```
$("p.site_text").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).children(":first").html());
```

});

Comment: I tried this code now and the div is still there:  
                 <p class='site_text'><div><b>Πετσέτα για την εξωτερική περιποίηση του αυτοκινήτου!</b></div><div>Οι πετσέτες μικροΐνας γενικής χρήσης, Workhorse towels, της Chemical Guys είναι ιδανικές &nbsp;και ανθεκτικές για κάθε μορφής εργασία. Έχουν απίστευτη αντοχή και είναι σχεδιασμένες να πλένονται πάρα πολλές φορές.</p>

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when using <script>
     
    $(document).ready(function($) {
       
    $("p.site_text").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).children(":first").html());

}); 
    </script>

Comment: you have not closed the document.ready function, change the code to <script> $(document).ready(function() { $("p.site_text").each(function() { $(this).html($(this).children(":first").html()); });}); </script>